# How to manually trigger an event and have change detection occur?

Tags: angular, testing, angular-changedetection

When I drag the root element of a component, assuming a drag listener is present in the component, for example:

```
@HostListener('drag', ['event'])
onDrag(e) { ... }
```

Every time the event occurs, so does the change detection, because an event is an asynchronous operation.

However, when triggering the drag event manually, I can't seem to have the change detection to occur.

```
let event = new Event('drag');
fixture.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This will call the drag listener, but will not trigger change detection.

Just to be clear, I know I can trigger the event manually, then call `detectChanges()` manually also, but I would like the event to trigger change detection as in a real life scenario.

Comment: That is real life scenarion - emulating event and forcing angular to react..

Comment: No in a real life scenario, the event would cause the component to run change detection

Comment: You didnt live long enough i guess :)

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, you're saying that there is no way to trigger an event manually and as a side effect have change detection being run?

Comment: Wait are we talking about unit tests?

Comment: Dude there is no even lifecycle in unit tests, so reaction to events..:>

Comment: There is definitely a lifecycle in unit tests, at least when you are using the `TestBed`. `fixture.detectChanges()` will call `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnDestroy` is called during the teardown.

Comment: Nope there is no lifecycle, and that is by design. Check angular docs regarding unit testing, its explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, `fixture.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);` does trigger change detection. This can easily be seen when spying on `component.ngZone.run`.